# How to add two datetime values in python using timedelta (datetime values are User input)

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I'm trying to subtract the number of days (user input) to a datetime. I have been trying to understand how to convert the "days" to timedelta type but have been unsuccessful, See code below: with what I have so far.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

expiry_input = input("Input Expiry Date: YYYY-MM-DD: ")
input_object = datetime.strptime(expiry_input, '%Y-%m-%d')

notice_non_renewal = input("Input Notice of Non-Renewal: ")
non_renewal_object = datetime.strptime(notice_non_renewal, '%d')

notice_day = input_object - non_renewal_object
print(notice_day)
```

Results in the following:

```
Input Expiry Date: YYYY-MM-DD: 2017-05-30

Input Notice of Non-Renewal: 30

42854 days, 0:00:00
```

The end result should be 2017-05-01

Comment: `print(non_renewal_object)` - that's not a `timedelta`.

Answer (score 0):

Build a `timedelta` object:

```
notice_non_renewal = int(input("Input Notice of Non-Renewal: "))
non_renewal_object = timedelta(days=notice_non_renewal)
```